# How SD card capacity limitation works? Is there a way to bypass it?

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, sd-card, memory-limit

For the longest time now, I have been hearing that, this phone can support up to 64 gigs for SD card expansion, that can support up to 128, and stuffs like that.

I am just wondering, how this limitation works!!

---

As far as I know, there is no limitation for the thumb drives, then why on SD cards?

I am using a Windows 8.1 tablet and it say's it can support up to 64 gigs of expansion. Although I haven't popped in a higher storage SD card, I am just curious to know, what ll happen if I do so.

And is there a way around it to make a higher capacity SD cards work on it?

Comment: Sometimes that kind of "limit" isn't meant as a spec, only advice that it has been successfully tested with one that large, more like a guarantee that it will work.  It might have been the largest size readily available to the public at the time the marketing materials were prepared.  It doesn't necessarily mean that a larger one won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In short, because they are having different spec, below image is the short summary of the three different type of SD:

[image]

In long, you may want to go through the [SD page in wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital), there is no way to bypass it since this is hardware limitation. (Of cause, unless you swap with different hardware with correct drive installed.)

Comment: my tablet supports `MicroSD, SDHC and SDXC`. If SDXC is 32GB - 2TB then how come it is restricted to only 64GB, and if it, it's not a hardware limitation.

Comment: Although it told you support up to 64GB only, you can insert a 128GB+ sd card.

Comment: @bilbo, then I ll just have to try and see for myself.